# Android: while screen in landscape, recalculate the size of image

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and currently have project on hand. I did search some solution from Google and StackOverflow. I really have no clue how to do it.

In the project i did specify the size of holder image for display well during listview rendering image. Besides that i did calculate the size of item in listview in order to expand the listview in scrollView. But when it comes to landscape, i want the size that i specified to be recalculate, so the child of listview (such as textView) can expand. And the image I specified in portrait can expand (full screen) in landscape as well.

Please help! What steps i need to take for re-calculating it? or is there any other solution?

Below is the example of my layout, the size of image in landscape is same as in portrait ,i.e., as i specified it. So what are the functions that i can call once i change the view mode? Thanks.

```
 ___________________
|...................|  ________________________________
|.                 .| |      ....................      |
|.Image Full Screen.| |      .                  .      |
|.                 .| |      . Image could not  .      |  
|...................| |      .   full screen    .      |
|                   | |      ....................      |
| Portrait mode     | |                                |
|                   | |       Land scape mode          |
|                   | |                                |
|                   | |________________________________|
|___________________|
```

Comment: Please put code snippet, your question is not clear enough

Comment: By default when screen changes orientation your app is restarted, so all your calculation code will be repeated. Unless you add some extra code to keep some data from previous run.

Comment: thanks for replied.. so what function can check the current orientation? is it onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)?

Comment: @NaiveBz You can create different (desired) layouts for the landscape and the portrait mode. Read some docs for reference like [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).